# Is there a word to describe words that look like antonyms but are synonyms?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Words like flammable/inflammable, valuable/invaluable, etc.

It doesn't look like there is a specific word to describe this phenomenon.

Comment: Ehm, "invaluable" is not exactly a synonym of "valuable".

Comment: @MrLister It’s close enough.

Comment: True, they don't have the exact same meaning but is there a term for this kind of thing? I think heterographic synonym would make sense but that's feels like a redundant form of synonym since most, if not all, synonyms are spelled differently from each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a name for synonyms that appear to have opposite meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57144/is-there-a-name-for-synonyms-that-appear-to-have-opposite-meanings)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a word for words that are their own opposites. These are called "contronyms". But, I don't believe there is a word for words that "appear" to be opposites but are actually synonymous.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contronym

http://mentalfloss.com/article/57032/25-words-are-their-own-opposites

However, each of your examples is not the same either. Flammable and inflammable do mean the same thing. They are actually two different synonymous words that have different origins. They were derived independently from English and Latin word usages.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/flammable-or-inflammable

Valuable and invaluable **do not** mean the same thing. The former means valuable within an estimation (worth an amount), while the latter means **not** valuable within any estimation (worth beyond any amount).

https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/invaluable-not-valuable-usage

Comment: I find that in common usage, *invaluable* is often just overstatement for *valuable*. The second most common usage for *invaluable* is like "priceless heirloom", meaning "could fetch about $3.50 at an antique dealer or pawn shop." Just my AmE opinion. I'd give you +2 for contronym if I could.